# ubuntu 18.04 server official release

Tags: ubuntu, server

Does anyone know where i can download the OFFICIAL release of Ubuntu 18.04 server for the pi4? All I can find on canonical's website is Ubuntu 20, which is incompatible with the software i need to run.

I have the unofficial one - https://jamesachambers.com/raspberry-pi-4-ubuntu-server-desktop-18-04-3-image-unofficial/

I'm after the official one, which seems to have completely disappeared.

Cheers!

Comment: There never was an official release because the Pi4 was released in 2019.

Answer (score 0):

https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04/release/

and

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi

the pi3 version works on a 4, despite the line on the latter link about it only being Ubuntu 19.10.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

https://ubuntu.com/download/server/arm

I think Ubuntu 20.04.2 is better than 18.04.